# Restsharp library not working correctly on the iPhone

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, restsharp

I made a program that uses Restsharp to communicate with a asp.net web api web service. All was fine in the simulator but the same code does not work on the actual iPhone. I am using the monotouch version of restsharp from **[here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/tree/master/RestSharp.MonoTouch)** . When debugging in the simulator I used the simulator version of the library, and when debugging on the iphone I used the one for the iPhone. On the iPhone `response.Data` is null. (BTW is there an easy way to automatically use the iphone version of the library when debugging on iphone and the simulator version of the library when debugging on the simulator?)

```
var hh = client.ExecuteAsync<List<Accommodation>>(request, (response) => {
    //on the simulator this works, on the device response.Data is null
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.Data != null)
        searchCompleteAction(response.Data);
    else
        searchCompleteAction(null);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
});
```

Comment: Just about the versions of the libraries, you don't need to switch between them at all, if the library works it will work on any kind of iOS device/simulator so you actually wasting you time switching between them and may be that's why you have the problem with that one that you use for iPhone

Comment: The restsharp.monotouch solution generated 2 libraries: one for simulator and one for phone. If I try to use the one for phone on the simulator it won't start. If I try to use the one for the simulator on the phone then it won't start either.

Comment: what do you mean under generated? You downloaded the sources of RestShart and build the libraries by your own?

Comment: Yes.....................

Comment: hmm, so at all that's a problem, please try to use this library https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp from `Xamarin Components`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the library you sent me and it is working now. If you add your comment as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `RestSharp` library [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp)  from `Xamarin Components`